# Cell value based on positions of neighbouring cells

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap

I want to know if there is a way to assign values to a raster cell based on the values and positions of neighbouring cells. To be more precise, I want to look for:

1. the occurance of neighbours with matching values,
2. the spatial relationship of matching and non-matching neighbours.

For example, these situations should result in different values (o = matching values):

```
1:
x x x
o o x
x x x

2:
x o x
x o x
x x x 

3:
x o o
x o x
o x x
```

Only the studied cell (the cell in the middle) should be assigned the new value, but all cells should be studied in the same way. To preserve the original raster, I guess the ideal would be to store the new values in a different raster.

To my understanding, focal statistics doesn't deal with spatial relationships in quite this manner, but maybe there is another way?

I use ArcMap 10.4.1.

Comment: Does your raster stores 2 values only, or more?

Comment: If it's possible for a raster to store more than one value, I guess it could. The raster is generated with the feature to raster tool, but it could be manipulated or created in a different way.

Comment: So using your examples what values do you actually want to compute and store? It's not clear want you are really wanting.

Comment: I'm not interested in working with or storing multiple values per cell, if that's what you're asking. At least not for the time being. The raster I'm currently working with has got one band.

Comment: My guess this is something to be solved by focal statistics with weight matrix, but question lacks details, so I am  voting to close it.

Comment: Without a better explanation of how you want to determine the new value from the neighbouring cells, all I can say is if focal statistics doesn't do what you need, look at the raster cell iterator in ArcGIS Pro 2.5 or later https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-spatial-analyst-blog/introducing-the-raster-cell-iterator/ba-p/886300